# How to check if imageview resource is right when using robot framework + Appiumlibrary mobile testing

Tags: robotframework, appium-android

I have simple Android app and I try to test it with Robot Framework and appiumlibrary combo. I struggle with the imageview checks. I have one imageview and image changes based on the values ​​calculated. Can I check is the image right (expected)? For example, if the calculated result is 30, the image should be ylip.jpg. How can I check that the resource/ image is correct? I have tried many ways and test don't run or I get valuerrors.

from Robot code:

> Element Should Be Visible     imageView2    //* [@id="imageView2"]/image[contains(@drawable, "norm.jpg")]

From layout:

> android:id="@+id/imageView2"

From activity:

```
else if (result >18.5 && result <=30){
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ylip);}
```

[image: Screenshot from app file:]

Answer (score 1):

To me I think UI Element inspector can't know the image resource name. If you really want to compare image there is one library call RobotEyes you can use it to compare the image. Second solution is you have to dynamic your resource-id  name in application to match your condition.

[RobotEyes](https://github.com/jz-jess/RobotEyes)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! So I tried to dynamic resource-id name but I'm not quite sure if this is right.  int idImage = getResources().getIdentifier("norm", "drawable", getOpPackageName());       image.setImageResource(idImage); Image shows correctly. But when I run test  with: Element Name Should Be        imageView2    idImage.  I'll get fail test result with: Element 'imageView2' name should be 'idImage' but it is ''.  Any idea where this is going wrong?